# How is Moq's It.IsAny<T>() implemented

Tags: c#, moq

For C#'s Moq, I went in through debugger, and noticed `It.IsAny<T>()` just compiles to a certain value of `T`, like `Guid.Empty` for `Guid`s, 0 for `int`s, etc.

How does Moq tell the difference between an `It.IsAny<T>` and the value that it compiles to?

Comment: Why don't you head over to GitHub and [see for yourself](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/It.cs#L54)

Comment: @ClausJørgensen: I wish I understood how that bit of code worked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey : I suspect you do... :)

Comment: I expanded what it actually does in a answer.

Answer (score 7):

Taking base in the [GitHub source code](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/It.cs#L54), what's really being matched is a given predicate of type `Predicate<T>` (or `Func<T, bool>` if you like):

```
value => value == null || typeof(TValue).IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType())
```

It checks if the `value` is null, or if the `value` is the same type as the `TValue` argument for `IsAny<TValue>` using [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It then returns the [`default(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value of the type to allow the mocked method to correctly match the signature. And as pointed out by DavidH, you can't use null for value types, which is why using default(T) is preferred as a generic return value.

Comment: Why does it return `default<T>`?

Comment: Because you cannot return null for value/struct types.

Answer (score 6):

The lambdas we use when we `Setup` mocks in Moq are *not* the usual delegates, they are ***expression trees***. The `It.Is<>` method is just a place-holder. It is not necessarily actually called. It is not important if it returns `default(T)` or just throws a `NotSupportedException` or something else. Let me give an example:

```
interface IMyFace
{
  void MethodToTest(object obj);
}

static class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    Setup<IMyFace>(x => x.MethodToTest(null));
    Setup<IMyFace>(x => x.MethodToTest(MyAnyA<object>()));
    Setup<IMyFace>(x => x.MethodToTest(MyAnyB<object>()));
  }

  public static TArg MyAnyA<TArg>()
  {
    // never runs
    return default(TArg);
  }
  public static TArg MyAnyB<TArg>()
  {
    // never runs
    return default(TArg);
  }

  public static void Setup<T>(Expression<Action<T>> expr) where T : class
  {
    Console.WriteLine("The expr was: " + expr);
  }
}
```

Not too interesting, but it should show that with expression trees `Expression<...>` you can see what method was used, and not just the returned value. Find out more on how to examine an expression tree on [MSDN, Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).